# Downloading open street map data in pbf format

Tags: download, openstreetmap

I want to download data of a specific area from open street map. Whenever I try to export from openstreetmap.org it downloads the data in .osm format but I want the data to be in .pbf format. I have tried converting .osm file to .pbf file using *osmconvert.exe* but whenever I try to open the converted file in a text editor ( geany to be specific) it shows nothing. But when I tried opening the converted file in vim there was something but not readable. Can someone suggest me a way to download the data of specific area from open street map in readable pbf format?

Comment: This might be more appropriate for http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For downloading area specific OSM files I would like to recommend the service of **Geofabrik**:
http://download.geofabrik.de/

The format **.osm** usually is *human-readable* since it's XML-structured text.

The format **.pbf** is *not human-readable* because this is a binary format. PBF-formatted OSM data are highly compressed and need to be converted (for example to .osm or to .csv) before you can read them.

Further information can be found in **OSM Wiki**:

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format